# User authentication using express and react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, redux

---

**PS
Just note I am pretty new with react(with redux) and express in general.
My question is more of a "what do I do now?" or "help me in the right direction,please" type of question.
My english is very bad.
I am not afraid to teach myself , just show me where to look.
Most internet resources are half explained or assumes you are a pro.**

---

I have a react client side application that needs user authentication, and after the authentication the react application needs to know if client is logged in or out

Now currently my react application is using conditional rendering which means my entire application is depended on the app-level state.

When my react application starts it starts with a login component where the user can add his email and password

Now from here on out I am completely stuck on what to do,so many questions...

How do I authenticate(from the backend) the user using his login input(email/password) and check agiants users in mongoDB if he is there or not, and if he is there how do I let front-end application know he is valid user and use that user information to access certain routes?

How can I check if user is logged in(after authentication and valid user have been authenticated) from front-end react application

Can I use cookies as a possible solution?For example set a cookie on the server-side(express) and access the cookie on the client-side(react) and vice-versa?

Little of topic(or maybe on topic) question? What is Passport.js and it help with my current dilemma ???

Comment: You will need to provide at least some code, with information about where you're stuck or what isn't working. I'd recommend googling some beginner tutorials to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Toby.....I found out I am using something called the "MERN" stack .....didn't know this mongo+express+react+node combination had a name....hahah so the question is very unspecific.....now looking into ways to authenticate user using the MERN stack .....good day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as authentication is concerned, using a JWT which will be saved in session storage and can be sent to your server app via API is a very popular approach with react/redux applications. this will be sent with all api requests so that the server app can verify that the user is logged in before serving data to them. to check if someone is logged in on the client app, you should have a reducer/saga/thunk that, upon recieving a successful login message from the server app, will update the auth reducer portion of the redux store to flip a boolean isLoggedIn property that you can expose to your props to check if you are logged in.

have a react client side application that needs user authentication, and after the authentication the react application needs to know if client is logged in or out

Now currently my react application is using conditional rendering which means my entire application is depended on the app-level state.

When my react application starts it starts with a login component where the user can add his email and password

there is a react-redux structure called the duck structure that is very good: https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

sorry but I do not have mongodb experience but search for authentication handling and there will definitely be examples. .NET Core is excellent and there are many tutorials if you consider changing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!!    I am following a tutorial that is why my question is sooo "uneducated "??....i guess.....Anyway I figured out that I am using the MERN stack and I am currently looking into JWT as was suggested by the tutorial also..THank you soo much just reconfirmed the approach I should look into.........Also .NET looks freakishly complicated but MERN stack does also so I don't hahah

Comment: No problem. If you can, and believe your question is answered, please mark my post as the answer. good luck with your project.